# tensorflow tf.train.batch only usable if images have same size?

Tags: tensorflow

```
left_name, right_name, occ_name = tf.train.slice_input_producer([left, right, label], shuffle=False)
l = tf.read_file(left_name)
l = tf.image.decode_png(l, channels=3)
r = tf.read_file(right_name)
r = tf.image.decode_png(r, channels=3)
o = tf.read_file(occ_name)
o = tf.image.decode_png(o, channels=1)
l_batch, r_batch, o_batch = tf.train.batch([l, r, o], batch_size=3)
```

Can I only use that if all images have the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the image tensors must be the same size before you batch. You can achieve this with [`tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_and_pad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_image_with_crop_or_pad). There may be other functions in `tf.image` that may be useful to you as well.